# Tried renaming a managed c++ project in Visual Studio, getting resource errors now

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I tried renaming a c++ project in Visual Studio and I'm now getting the following errors:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find any resources appropriate for
>   the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "OuiDesktop.PreForm.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into
>   assembly "OuiProject" at compile time, or that all the satellite
>   assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

I get this for every each form that uses a resource. If I comment these lines of code out that raise this error, the program launches okay, but I need the resources.

What have i done wrong? Seems renaming a project in Visual Studio is a nightmare!!

These .resources files are being created in the build directory just fine, just not being included in the assembly!

Comment: Renaming projects or solutions in Visual Studio has _always_ been a nightmare! When I needed to do it, I always created a new project/solution and copied what I needed into it.

Comment: I tried doing this after trying to rename, initially the OuiDesktop.PreForm.resources files were prefixed with the old project name, until I completely redid the project. So that was fixed, but it still complains they're not in the assembly. They're being compiled in the build directory tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Visual Studio Express 2010 on this machine. Creating a new project and adding the  source files back into that in Express didn't work.

I tried this same fix on another machine with full Visual Studio 2010 Professional and it worked perfectly.